# S3 Advanced Redirection Rules: The same prefix text containing issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I try to use an S3 bucket for my redirection need. It's for publicly available downloadable files. I want my customers use the same URL but I like to change the the file path. Anyway, I faced an issue with the JSON rules. I tested with two URLs. One of them is the base string and the other one is like base + something. Let me put my JSON rules:

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "download"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "abc.com",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "abc1.zip"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "download2"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "abc.com",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "abc2.zip"
        }
    }
]
```

When I use the download URL it works. When I use download2 URL it doesn't work.
It gives me something like that:

```
https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com/abc1.zip2
```

Does anybody know to solve this? Or do I have to use different text for each rule?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I needed to use ReplaceKeyWith instead of ReplaceKeyPrefixWith name.

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "download"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "abc.com",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyWith": "abc1.zip"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "download2"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "abc.com",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyWith": "abc2.zip"
        }
    }
]
```